# How to use htmlspecialchars in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, htmlspecialchars

This is my code, it will echo "Not working"

```
    $f = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
    $text = htmlspecialchars( $f );

        $matches = array();
        preg_match('@<a.*?</a>@s', $text, $matches);
        if ($matches) {
            $text2 = $matches[0];
            echo $text2;
        }
        else {
            echo "Not working";
        }
```

If I made a variable:

```
$text = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> is your best friend!';
```

This will work somehow, but it wont when I take it from the:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars( $f );
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) translates all special characters `<&>"'`, etc into [html entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) (e.g., `&` becomes `&amp;`). Thus your match fails.

Answer (score 2):

htmlspecialchars will convert from

```
<
```

to

```
&lt;
```

etc. 
[See the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)